# JPA: single table inheritance possible performance tradeoff

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, single-table-inheritance

I have following MS SQL DB tables, where I am storing school related data:

*HighSchools<---GradeLevels<---Courses<---CourseGrades*

The relations between the tables looks like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GradeLevels", schema = "dbo")
public class HighSchoolGradeLevel {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "AttendedId", nullable = false)
    private HighSchoolAttended highSchoolAttended;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "highSchoolGradeLevel")
    @OrderBy("createdDate ASC") 
    private List<HighSchoolCourse> highSchoolCourses = new ArrayList<>(0);

// other fields and getter/setter methods....
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Courses", schema = "dbo")
public class HighSchoolCourse {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "GradeLevelId", nullable = false)
    private HighSchoolGradeLevel highSchoolGradeLevel;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "highSchoolCourse", cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @OrderBy("createdDate ASC") 
    private List<HighSchoolCourseGrade> highSchoolCourseGrades = new ArrayList<>(0);

// other fields and getter/setter methods....

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CourseGrades", schema = "dbo")
public class HighSchoolCourseGrade {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CourseId", nullable = false)
    private HighSchoolCourse highSchoolCourse;

// other fields and getter/setter methods....

}
```

The java web-app users can do CRUD operations with the tables data.

The new requirement is to consume the data with the same structure from a third party. The consumed data **SHOULD NOT** be displayed for the web-app users.

Therefore, I am thinking to use JPA single table inheritance which allows me to:

- avoid adding clones of the existing tables
- avoid cloning existing business logic which is tight to existing
  entity types
- avoid code refactoring of existing CRUD ops in case implementing own discriminator column.

The Single table inheritance looks reasonable to use in my, but there is one thing I am not sure about **"What is the performance trade off of using Single Table Inheritance, especially while operating on the Parent and its Childs entities?"**. The question may sound dummy, knowing the fact that Hibernate will update SQL queries with corresponding `discriminator` statements. But still it would be nice to improve the current knowledge and be sure that the existing users of wep-app will not get bad usage experience.

The existing web-app DAO layer uses with Spring Data JPA. Currently, each of existing tables contains more than ~500k records.